# How can I flip the columns and rows of this output from gt_summary()?

Tags: r, gtsummary

Here is a brief overview of a tibble:

```
> test
# A tibble: 78 × 3
   Year  Anaesthesia         `Theatre time (mins)`
   <fct> <chr>                               <dbl>
 1 2015  General anaesthetic                   240
 2 2016  General anaesthetic                   270
 3 2016  General anaesthetic                   260
 4 2016  General anaesthetic                   320
 5 2017  General anaesthetic                   195
 6 2017  General anaesthetic                   210
 7 2017  General anaesthetic                   185
 8 2017  General anaesthetic                   185
 9 2017  General anaesthetic                   235
10 2017  General anaesthetic                   250
# ℹ 68 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

I want to display median & IQR theatre times for the different categories of 'year' and 'anaesthesia'

Two simple gt_summaries for output:

```
test %>%
  select(
    c(
      Year,
      `Theatre time (mins)`
      )) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = Year
    )

test %>%
  select(
    c(
      Anaesthesia,
      `Theatre time (mins)`
      )) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = Anaesthesia
    )
```

Give me output quite like what I want:

[image: gt summary output for year]

and:

[image: gt summary output for anaesthesia]

These are nice, but I feel that the rows and columns would be better flipped. Especially as I would potentially like to have a second time based measurement to make another median (IQR) column out of.

But for now, I would like ONE summary table with Year and Anaesthesia as the 'Characteristics' (with their own 'levels') and median (IQR) of Theatre time as the statistic. I am certain this will ultimately be straightforward and I just lack the syntax skills.

I have tried and wrangled my brain and searched repeatedly but haven't found the answer or a similar enough question to work this out on my own.

Thanks

Comment: Does `gtsummary::tbl_continuous()` do what you need?

Comment: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_continuous.html

Comment: Thank you so much for such a prompt reply. I only discovered `gt_summary` this year and didn't actually realise there was more to it than `tbl_summary`. Massive face palm. I will post an example of how easy this is. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, thanks to the reply. Here is my input (slightly different nibble & variable names):

```
theatreTimeData %>%
  select(
    c(
      Year,
      Anaesthesia,
      theatreTime
      )) %>%
  tbl_continuous(
    variable = theatreTime
    )
```

And output (just needing some prettification which I'll work on myself):

[image: tbl_continuous output]

Thanks, Daniel!